# pick from random list and decrement result for next pick

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

What i'm trying to accomplish is to pick randomly from a list of people in column A, however once they have been picked, they should be removed from the list. The idea is to create a roster which will randomly pick someone every week - but remove the person once they are picked (and recreate the array once its 0)

```
Example

Paul
David
John
Matt
```

by running the random(A1:A4) , I may get David as my pick, however the next time I run the function the Array is built again from A1:A4 - therefore David isnt removed.

I tried adding a second column to track picks, and then delete them from an array, however I was only able to remove 1 value from the array without retaining what was done

```
Example

List of Users      Tracking        Result (print all values)
Paul                               John   David,Paul,Matt
David              John            David  Paul,Matt
John               David           Matt   Paul,John
Matt               Matt            David  Paul,John
```

Although the Result isnt all values, i included all values to show the logical issue I am having. In the tracking column, I left the first blank so that the value in the tracking field is the value I get from result(result only gets 1 value normally)..so B2 = C1

Can I get some pointers on how to do this. (google-apps-script)

For those asking for the code here it is

```
function random(a,b) {
  var listPeople = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var row = a[i];
    for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
      var value = row[j];
      if (value) {
        listPeople.push(value); 
      }
    }
  }
//deleting someone
  var trackPeople = listPeople.slice(0);
  for (var i = 0; i < trackPeople.length; i++) {
    if (trackPeople[i] == b) {
      trackPeople.splice(i,1);
    }
  } 
// Returning a persons name
  if (trackPeople.length > 0) {
    var pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * trackPeople.length);
    return trackPeople[pick];
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your current script so we might add improvements. Apart from that your best search on the internet might be to look for pick-random-and-take-the-pick-out in some form, and only once you can see the logic clearly translate it to the apps-script. If you need a general guide for learning the apps-script then look for that...

Comment: Without your code, it's difficult to help. We would have to write entirely it for you :-/

Comment: Added the code to the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have pieced together this below, using some of your code. It expects a spreadsheet with  a blank Column A ; puts in the the random chosen Name in Cell B1, and rewrites the depleted list back into Col A.

```
function pickAPerson(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("your_spreadsheet_id_here").getSheets()[0];
  var completeList = [["Paul"],["David"],["John"],["Matt"]]; //this list can be as long as necessary // you could also get this list from another spreadsheet range, for example
  var currentList = [];
  var columnWithNames = "A"; // expects: start in row 1; no empty cells 
  try{var populatedRange = getPopulatedRange(ss,columnWithNames); currentList = populatedRange.getValues(); populatedRange.clear()}
  catch (e) {currentList = completeList; Logger.log(e)} //if the ss list is exhausted, currentList will be filled from the completList array
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentList.length);
  var theChosenOne = currentList.splice(randomIndex,1)
  if(currentList.length>0)
  ss.getRange(1,1,currentList.length,1).setValues(currentList);
  ss.getRange("B1").setValue(theChosenOne)
}

function getPopulatedRange(ss,column) { //Returns the range in a single column from row 1 to the last populated cell in that column
  var lastRow = ss.getMaxRows();
  var values = ss.getRange(column + "1:" + column + lastRow).getValues();
  for (; values[lastRow - 1] == "" && lastRow > 0; lastRow--) {}
  return ss.getRange(column  + "1:" + column + lastRow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The task is very easy with [R programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R_(programming_language)) language. The following code stores the numbers **11-100** to *numbers* variable. *num* is a random number from the *numbers*. The next line erases selected number (*num*) from *numbers*. Running the function again selects another number from the truncated list.

The Rstudio screenshot shows the code and the output. You can see the selected number 13 is absent the updated list.

[image: Rstudio screen]

```
numbers <- 11:100
select_num <- function(){
  num <- sample(numbers,1)
  numbers <<- numbers[numbers!=num]
  print(paste0("This time the number ", num, " has been selected"))
  
}

select_num()
numbers
```